# CRM 2011 On-Premise: Qualify Lead to Account/Contact disabled

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am currently unable to qualify a Lead to either an Account or Contact, however I am able to qualify to an Opportunity.  I have checked security permissions for creating Accounts and Contacts with the user I am using (trying this on the Admin user with all privileges yields the same result):

Is there something I'm missing to allow Leads to be converted to Accounts and Contacts?

Comment: What happens when you use this?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547458.aspx

Comment: That sample code appears to work - I was able to pass in an existing Lead Id and the code created an Account and Contact without an issue.  The problem seems to be confined to the Qualify Lead dialog :/

Comment: Any error message? What happens when you try?

Comment: When I click on the Qualify button, the Account and Contact options on the dialog are greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem was a modification to the conv_lead.aspx file in the CRM installation directory, the customer had previously needed these fields to be disabled and since there is no supported way to disable them, the source code had been amended and two lines of code were added:

```
cbAddAccount.disabled = true;
cbAddContact.disabled = true;
```

Removing this code restored the original functionality of this screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you populating the default, out of the box name and company name fields? I have noticed that when I don't populate a company name an account isn't created when converting.

Comment: Yes, I checked that all these fields were populated.  I found the cause of the problem, answer below